# Mixing Spring MVC with inline PHP

Tags: java, php, spring-mvc

I was wondering if it's possible to write PHP code inline within Spring MVC pages.

Something like

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
      xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" >

    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  
    <jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" /> 

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />    
        <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title"/></title>
        <util:load-scripts />
        <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" />

    </head>

    <body style="background-image: url(${resources}/images/Main_bg.jpg);">
        <div id="wrapper">
                    <lang:PHP>
                        require_once(somephpfile.php);
                        ...
```

I have a massive piece of legacy PHP code that I want to integrate into an even bigger system I'm building, the new system is written with Spring and Spring MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. For instance by running php from within the JVM using [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) and you probably need to write some sort of custom tag.

Answer (score 1):

This library allows you to use php in spring as dynamic language and template engine.
https://github.com/PaulWeb/quercusspring